# use standard values if there is no overlap in table columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table ce_relations and a table ce_values which i want to combine to a table ce_combined_values. The ce_combined_values table should have the exact same amount of rows as ce_relations. The query stated below does however only return the rows where the user_id and friend_id is existing in the ce_values.user_id column. I tried to solve this problem by using the IFNULL statement, but i guess there is also an extra condition missing in the WHERE clausule... any help is welcome!

```
INSERT INTO ce_combined_values (user_id, friend_id, relation_degree, user_value, friend_value, relation_value)
SELECT a.user_id, a.friend_id, a.relation_degree,  IFNULL(b.1d_value, 0)  as user_value, IFNULL(c.1d_value, 0) as friend_value, Least(b.1d_value, c.1d_value) as relation_value
FROM  ce_relations a, ce_values b, ce_values c
WHERE a.relation_degree = 1 AND b.user_id = a.user_id AND c.user_id = a.friend_id AND b.user_id <> c.user_id

Union all

//same select query is used for relation_degree 2 with 2d_values and relation_degree 3 with 3d_values.
```

EDIT:

For example this is what I want to achieve:

table ce_relations:

```
+---------+-----------+-----------------+
| user_id | friend_id | relation_degree |
+---------+-----------+-----------------+
|       1 |         3 |               1 |
|       2 |         1 |               1 |
|       3 |         4 |               1 |
+---------+-----------+-----------------+
```

table ce_values:

```
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| user_id | 1d_value | 2d_value | 3d_value |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
|       1 |        5 |       10 |       33 |
|       2 |       10 |       12 |       44 |
|       3 |       20 |       13 |       55 |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
```

should become ce_combined values ( deleted relation_degree and relation_value for readability)

```
+---------+-----------+------------+--------------+
| user_id | friend_id | user_value | friend_value |
+---------+-----------+------------+--------------+
|       1 |         3 |          5 |           20 |
|       2 |         1 |         10 |            5 |
|       3 |         4 |         20 |            0 |
+---------+-----------+------------+--------------+
```

but currently returns ( the row with friend_id = 4 is missing because it doesn't exist in ce_values)

```
+---------+-----------+------------+--------------+
| user_id | friend_id | user_value | friend_value |
+---------+-----------+------------+--------------+
|       1 |         3 |          5 |           20 |
|       2 |         1 |         10 |            5 |
+---------+-----------+------------+--------------+
```

Comment: The ce_combined_values table should have the exact same amount of rows as ce_relations. The query stated below does however only return the rows where the user_id and friend_id is existing in the ce_values.user_id column---

Not clear what you are trying to achieve. Can you give an example?

Comment: It isn't clear what you need your output to be.  If you are using a `UNION ALL`, the output will be the number of rows in the first table+the number of rows in the next table.

Comment: I am not sure, but it sounds as though you want a `left join`

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I added an example in the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you need to LEFT JOIN your tables. And I don't think you need to UNION ALL the same query three times with just a different filter condition.

Maybe that helps you:

```
SELECT a.user_id, a.friend_id, a.relation_degree, 
       IFNULL(b.value, 0) as user_value, 
       IFNULL(c.value, 0) as friend_value, 
       Least(b.value, c.value) as relation_value
  FROM ce_relations a
  LEFT
  JOIN ce_values b
    ON a.user_id = b.user_id 
  LEFT
  JOIN ce_values c
    ON a.friend_id = c.user_id
   AND b.user_id <> c.user_id
 WHERE a.relation_degree IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! Unfortunately I wasn't totally clear. A left join wont help because i need values from different columns for each relation degree. ce_values.1d_value for degree 1, ce_values.2d_value for degree 2 and ce_values.3d_value for degree 3

Comment: But I can perform a left join for each degree and then Union them...I got it working now. Thanks for the slap in the face!